# Spectral norm of a matrix construction

Tags: linear-algebra

Say I have a -singular matrix $B$. How do I show that the spectral norm of the complement is at least 1.

Comment: $B$ is a red herring. You are subtracting a singular matrix from the identity. Take a vector from the kernel of that singular matrix, and see what you can do with it.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** For a matrix $M$, $\|I - M\| \geq \rho(I - M)$